# Using Tesseract OCR for Character Segmentation Only

Tags: python, tesseract, text-segmentation

I want to do text segmentation on a printed document. I already segment the document to the character segmentation but i failed when i meet some touching character. I want to use the Tesseract OCR only to segment the word. I know Tesseract can do this task, but i dont know how to access that without digging the internal code of tesseract. Can anyone give some advice for me? If it is possible, i need that in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can call [`TessBaseAPIGetComponentImages`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/api/capi.h) API method, you can retrieve the segmentation at various `pageIteratorLevel` levels (Symbol/Character, Word, Line, etc.) without performing actual OCR on the image.

Comment: Can you describe how this can be done using python as in pytesseract, textract , pyocr?